# Find the area of an equilateral triangle given the distances from an interior point to the vertices

Tags: geometry, math-software

> Given the distances from an interior point to the vertices of an equilateral triangle, find the area of that triangle.

I have already tried equating $\sqrt{3}\times a^2/4$ and sum of the area of three triangles interior to equilateral triangle  formed by given lines. But that approach is making a hard equation to solve.

Any solution using Computer programming language may also help.

Comment: Is it "distance", meaning one is considering the centre of the triangle, or _distances_, meaning the distance may vary between vertices? The latter problem would be significantly harder.

Comment: Distance may vary...Let say an interior point is p of a triangle ABC then distances PA, PB, PC may be 5,3,4.

Comment: Almost the same question that was asked and answered about a month ago, that has specific lengths for the distances. I'm not sure how it changes if the distances are unspecified, but this other answer may provide useful information anyway:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/329761/equilateral-triangle-geometric-problem

Answer (score 3):

The following relation holds:
$$3(p^4+q^4+t^4+a^4)=(p^2+q^2+t^2+a^2)^2$$
where
$p,q,t$ are the distances from the vertices and $a$ is the length of the side of the triangle

Comment: As a hint this seems to be pretty....er...thrifty. Perhaps you could explain a little more this equality, and how could it be used to solve the problem.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equilateral_triangle

Comment: knowing $p,q,t$ you get an equation in $a$ which can be solved using a little elementary algebra

Comment: Thanks @Riccardo, yet I can see in that link a much helpful (imo) relation two lines below the one you wrote down. Good +1

Comment: Oh, not *so* little, @Riccardo...not even close: you get a rather nasty biquadratic , and the OP also had already a nasty equation. I don't think this one would be making his life much easier...

Comment: @DonAntonio: if you know $p,q,t$, you can put $p^2+q^2+t^2=b$ and $p^4+q^4+t^4=c$, so your equation becomes:$3(c+a^4)=(b+a^2)^2$. Maple gives the four solutions without problems.

Comment: You're right, @Riccardo. Didn't see those ones, yet it still requires quite some work as I don't assume solutions given by Maple, Gap, Mathematica or WA are welcome...

Answer (score -1):

According to the link given by @Greg (above), the area of the equilateral triangle ABC with an interior point P, will be 
((sqrt(3)*(PA^2+PB^2+PC^2)/4) + 3*(area formed by triangle with 3 lines as PA, PB and PC))/2]]

Comment: Whatever link @Greg provided it has now disappeared.

Comment: As my try, the `sqrt(3)*(PA^2+PB^2+PC^2)/4` should be `sqrt(3)*(PA^2+PB^2+PC^2)/8`

Answer (score -1):

let $x,y,z$ be the distances between the interior point and vertices.
$$x+y+z = a\sqrt{3}$$
$$a = \frac{x+y+z}{\sqrt{3}}$$

---

$$area = \sqrt{3}\frac{a^2}{4} = \sqrt{3}\frac{(x+y+z)^2}{12}$$

Comment: First statement here is incorrect. User might be thinking of Viviani's Theorem which states that the sum of distances of an interior point from sides of an equilateral triangle equals the altitude of the triangle.