# Area of a triangle formed by distances between vertices of a given triangle and an arbitrary point

Tags: geometry, triangles

> Let $\triangle ABC$ be an equilateral triangle with side $a$. $M$ is a point such that $MS = d$ where $S$ is the centroid of $\triangle ABC$. Prove that the area of the triangle whose sides are of length $MA,MB,MC$ is $[\frac{\root \of3}{12}]|a^2 - 3d^2|$

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1220918) results in this equation: 
$$[ABC] = 1.5 * [T] + \frac{\root \of 3}{8}(MA^2 + MB^2 + MC^2)$$
(Where $[x]$ is the area of $x$ and $T$ is the triangle we need to find the area for.)

which on rearranging gives,
$$[T] = \frac{\root \of 3}{6}(a^2 - \frac{1}{2}(MA^2 + MB^2 + MC^2))$$
So can we derive a relation between $d$ and $MA,MB,MC$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for the centroid $G$ of any triangle $ABC$ and $M$ a point we have
$$MA^2 + MB^2 + MC^2= GA^2 + GB^2 + GC^2 + 3MG^2$$

This you can show using vectors and $\vec{GA}+\vec{GB}+\vec{GC}=\vec{0}$.